# Two function not Riemann Stieltjes integrable

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

I am looking for a simple example without delving too deep into analysis, of two functions $f,g$ on an interval $[a,b]$ for the Riemann Stieltjes integral $\int fdg$ taken over $[a,b]$ does not exist

Comment: $g(x)=x$ and $f$ the indicator function of the rationals.

Comment: $g(x)=x$ and $f$ your favorite non-Riemann integrable function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy example that meets the wording of your question, namely $f(x)$ is the rationals indicator function and $g(x)$ the identity function:
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} 1 & x \in \Bbb Q \\ 0 & x \not\in \Bbb Q\end{array}\right.\\g(x) = x
$$
Since the indicator function is not Reimann integrable, the (Riemann-Stieltjes) integral $\int f(x)\,dg(x) = \int f\,dx$ does not exist.

(The main reason is that no matter how finely you slice the real line, the min and max of the function within each slice will differ by $1$.)

A much more interesting sort of question is to find example of two functions $f$ and $g$ which are each Riemann integrable, such that (RS)  $\int f\,dg$ does not exist, or to find two non-integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\int f\,dg$ does exist.

My hunch is that you can prove that if $f$ and $g$  are each Riemann integrable, then   $\int f\,dg$ must exist, and that you *can* find two non-integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\int f\,dg$ does exist.

Comment: No to 1 since if $g$ jumps at a point (limit left exists but different limit right) $f$ must be continuous there, so taking $f=g=[x]$ on $[.5,1.5]$ gives a counterexample

Comment: Yes trivially to 2 since you can make disjoint non-integrability ($f=0$ on $[0,2]$, $f$ your favorite Riemann non integrable on $[2,3]$ and $g=0$ on $[1,3]$, your favorite Riemann non integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ is continuous, should $\int_a^b f dg$ exist? (This is true if $f$ is monotone which appears in most textbooks.)